# How to convert string booleans expressed in local language into boolean

Tags: r, boolean, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I have a large dataset collected in **local language**, where each bolean column use the word "PRAWDA" for TRUE and "FAŁSZ" for FALSE.

So far, the dataframe stores those values as a column with factors with 2 levels: "FAŁSZ" and "PRAWDA". **My aim is to have the column which will be full of booleans, not string values.**

How could I convert all the booleans expressed in Polish into English ones?

Comment: Could you add your data as a `dput`. Maybe just map FALSZ to FALSE and PRAWDA to TRUE with an `ifelse(string=="PRAWDA", TRUE, FALSE)` assuming that's all there is. Otherwise a nested ifelse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just a boolean, use `==` to check for 'PRAWDA', which returns TRUE for those cases that match 'PRAWDA' and FALSE otherwise.  As there is only two values, this should be sufficient

```
df1$col2 <- df1$col1 == 'PRAWDA'
```

---

If there are multiple columns, use a loop

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(all(x %in% c('PRAWDA', 'FALSZ'), na.rm = TRUE)) x == 'PRAWDA' else x)
```

Comment: It would work, but despite boolean variables the dataframe is full of numerical values as well. I can't apply this method to all columns, as it will modify numericals as well

Comment: @AdamKuzański Your question is not clear to me.  The code I showed convers the single column (as I assume your question was  about a single column) to a boolean

Comment: @AdamKuzański Also, if your locale setting is in polish, perhaps, even `as.logical(df1$col1)` should work

Comment: Yes, I didn't write this clearly in the question, but your suggestions should work for my case anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: @AdamKuzański Also, some cases `type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)` should also work.  It depends on your locale setting though.  I updated for the case with mulitple columns